# How to call a VF page with controller with custom button in lightning experience

Tags: custom-button

Now that javascript button are out in the lightning experience, i am looking to call a VF page which uses a controller from custom button.

I chose the content source as URL and built the url as '/apex/FB_Campaign'.

Clicking the button takes you

> URL No Longer Exists error

Any thoughts on how to call the VF page

Comment: Why you are not using the content source as a Visualforce page? and if you are using are you putting the url as '/apex/FB_Campaign' or /apex/FB_Campaign ?

Comment: only reason the Vf page uses a controller class and not a standard controller.

Comment: what url are you using -- > '/apex/FB_Campaign' or /apex/FB_Campaign ?

Comment: We should not be using the quotes. just use /apex/FB_campaign. Works now

Comment: Even you can use visualforce page having a custom controller in the button with content source as a visualforce page. If you are using /apex/FB_Campaign then your button should be work fine even in lightning.  Once try with this in your url -{!URLFOR("/apex/FB_Campaign ")}

Comment: I am not sure you can using VF page as VF does not show up on the drop down to select. Or am i missing something here. And using the url without quotes works fine in LEX as well

Comment: It will come when you define standardController and use you apex class as an extension. I forget to mention this point.

Comment: Thats exactly the point, this VF page is been used at mutiple objects and i dont want to change something now on the page as it would affect other points